# I simply start video on my local computer, remotely

Tags: remote, execute-command

I simply want to start and play a video on my local computer screen from a remote device. is its possible? im using vlc and u have created a playlist. i want to  execute or send command remotely to start playing on the screen attached to the local... any detail help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ssh into your linux box, then run:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Then run the command to launch your video player:

```
vlc video.m4v
```

EDIT: Note you will need to ssh into the linux box as the same user that is logged into the desktop session.

EDIT2: Unless you want to run the application on the device from which you are connecting via ssh, then that is different. For that look into ssh X11 forwarding: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely